# How can I convert .txt file to .vcf format by using command line terminal on Mac?

Tags: linux, bash, macos

How can I convert .txt file to .vcf format by using bash or command line terminal on Mac? What tools I need to install for it? Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about Microsoft Address Book vCards or Variant Call Format?

Comment: Variant Call Format

Answer (score 0):

Coverting a `.txt` file into a `.vcf` file would depend on which formatting you have on the `.txt` file -- if it is formatted properly (formatted as a `.vcf` file should be), then just changing the file extension from `.txt` to `.vcf` would do the trick. You could create a `.vcf` copy of your `.txt` file to see if it works:

```
cp -a /folder/file.txt /newfolder/file.vcf
```

If your `.txt` file is not correctly formatted to the `.vcf` standards, I believe you are looking at some "hand-fixing" time on the `.txt` file (depending on what it contains) to ever be able to convert successfully.

Also, you might need/want to install the program `VCFtools` ([link](https://vcftools.github.io/index.html)) if you intend to work with `vcf` files.